# How to get count of all nested arrays in mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For a given sample data as follows:

```
{
    name: "School 1",
    classes: [
        {
            name: "Class 1",
            students: [
                {
                    name: "Student 1"
                },
                {
                    name: "Student 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Class 2",
            students: [
                {
                    name: "Student 3"
                },
                {
                    name: "Student 4"
                },
                {
                    name: "Student 5"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
{
    name: "School 2",
    classes: [
        {
            name: "Class 3",
            students: [
                {
                    name: "Student 6"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Class 4",
            students: [
                {
                    name: "Student 7"
                },
                {
                    name: "Student 8"
                }
        },
        {
            name: "Class 5",
            students: [
                {
                    name: "Student 9"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the count of classes within each school, and count of students within each class. So a projected output would look like this:

```
    {
    name: "School 1",
    classesCount: 2,
    classes: [
        {
            name: "Class 1",
            studentsCount: 2
        },
        {
            name: "Class 2",
            studentsCount: 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "School 2",
    classesCount: 3,
    classes: [
        {
            name: "Class 3",
            studentsCount: 1
        },
        {
            name: "Class 4",
            studentsCount: 2
        },
        {
            name: "Class 5",
            studentsCount: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to use the following query to get the number of classes per school, but couldn't get further count of students per class:

```
db.getCollection('Schools').aggregate([
{
  $project: {
      name: 1, //name of school
     classesCount: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$classes" }, then: { $size: "$classes" }, else: "NA"} },
     classes: ??
  }
}
])
```

What should the query look like for this result? The query should also handle null or 0 elements for any class and student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to apply to each class, so you can get the size of sudents for this class.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      classes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$classes",
          as: "classes",
          in: {
            name: "$$classes.name",
            studentsCount: {
              $size: "$$classes.students"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test the query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nonM7R81RT0).

Comment: in addition to above, if i have tons of schools, is it possible to filter some out and project only certain ones? for ex. by school name, or by number of classes (==0, > 0, etc.) so that the projection list is tiny

Comment: look for $project stage before this one, with $filter operator. Be sure to place it before, for performances reasons

Comment: looks like that only filters classes and students though, so the final projectio n would still show all schools. Could u show how to show only schools with 2 or less classes? so above scenario would only output one school.

Comment: As classes is an array at first level, you can simply use a $match stage with $size
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hq_1Bn54unr

Comment: yup! $match stage is what i needed, thanks @matthPen!

Comment: strangely i'm getting an error saying `bad query: BadValue: unknown top level operator: $expr`

Comment: db.version() gives 3.2.22

Comment: and i see that $expr is new in v 3.6

Comment: are there any alternatives that's supported in v 3.2.22? `$expr` seems to work great in your example but unfortunately isn't supported. I can't update my mongo server atm.

Comment: Here's a workaround for 3.2
https://mongoplayground.net/p/5npA53YKhQA